# What is the most optimal way to push different items to arrays in each document in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

i.e. I have such collections:

```
   { a: [2] }
   { a: [3] }
   { a: [4] }
```

And I want it to become like that

```
   { a: [2, 4] }
   { a: [3, 9] }
   { a: [4, 16] }
```

How am I supposed to do that in one query?

Comment: See [`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/). You cannot update by selective match in one "operation" but you can submit "multiple operations" in one request and response.

Comment: Thanks a lot :-)